# I am not able to use Angular material in my project

Tags: angular, installation, node-modules, package.json, angular-material-6

While using angular material i am getting following error please help me out:
these are the errors that i am getting in my console in my chrome browser

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>   at platform.es5.js:102
>   at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/platform.es5.js (platform.es5.js:104)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js (a11y.es5.js:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/autocomplete.es5.js (autocomplete.es5.js:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/material.es5.js (material.es5.js:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
>   client:148 [WDS] Warnings while compiling.
>   warnings @ client:148
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2356:55-73
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/bottom-sheet.es5.js 844:56-74
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/datepicker.es5.js 101:59-77
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js 1027:57-75
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/paginator.es5.js 80:58-76
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js 1049:53-71
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/sort.es5.js 412:59-77
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/stepper.es5.js 61:56-74
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/bidi.es5.js 91:56-74
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/observers.es5.js 38:65-83
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/observers.es5.js 195:57-75
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 488:55-73
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 1393:62-80
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2070:58-76
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js 1478:59-77
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2988:54-72
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/platform.es5.js 102:50-68
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js 88:54-72
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js 318:60-78
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/collections.es5.js 524:67-85
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js 663:58-76
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js 2337:55-73
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 527:63-81
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 826:67-85
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 932:58-76
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 4174:64-82
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 5050:68-86
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/text-field.es5.js 146:57-75
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 488:145-153
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/bottom-sheet.es5.js 844:217-225
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 1393:166-174
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/bottom-sheet.es5.js 844:240-248
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2070:154-162
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2070:186-194
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2070:204-212
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js 1049:139-147
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2356:145-153
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2356:188-196
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/bottom-sheet.es5.js 844:148-156
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2356:226-234
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js 1049:158-166
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2988:142-150
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2988:160-168
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js 1049:183-191
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/platform.es5.js 102:130-138
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js 1049:203-211
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js 88:142-150
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js 1049:233-241
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js 318:160-168
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js 318:184-192
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js 1049:260-268
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/text-field.es5.js 146:171-179
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js 663:154-162
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js 663:172-180
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/bottom-sheet.es5.js 844:167-175
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js 2337:145-153
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js 2337:165-173
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/bottom-sheet.es5.js 844:187-195
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 527:169-177
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 527:197-205
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 527:222-230
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 527:240-248
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/bidi.es5.js 91:148-156
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 826:181-189
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js 1027:151-159
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 932:154-162
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js 1027:176-184
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 4174:172-180
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 4174:197-205
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 4174:217-225
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 4174:237-245
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/observers.es5.js 195:151-159
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 5050:184-192
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js 1027:200-208
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/text-field.es5.js 146:151-159
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154
>   client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 2356:206-214
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
>   warnings @ client:154

i have tried to install angular material using following cli command
npm i angular-material

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "shop-managment",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.19",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 7.3.5.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatToolbarModule,MatButtonModule,MatSidenavModule,MatIconModule,MatListModule,MatCardModule} from '@angular/material';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


login.ts(my component where i used angular material)

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.less']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**login.html**

```
<mat-card>Login</mat-card>
```

i expect to display login in mat-card directive without any error in console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, revert your changes.

Remove this line as well: "angular-material": "^1.1.19",
It is for Angular 1, not Angular 2+.

Then install dependencies with: npm install

Run command: ng add @angular/material@^7.3.7

Say 'y' when it asks you about adding hammer.js and animations module.

Official guideline for material 7:
https://v7.material.angular.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use @angular/material and @angular/cdk version 8.1.1 since your angular dependencies is still at 7.2.0

download the version 7.2.0

```
npm install @angular/material@7.2.0.
```

Also you have installed angular material version 1, **"angular-material": "^1.1.19"** , not sure why this is required

Comment: it is not working getting same error

Comment: I replaced v8 with v7.2.0. and it works like a charm, thank you!